# Запрос MySQL на выборку категорий

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте, товарищи знатоки.

Есть таблица “category” с деревом категорий

```
|id|parent_id|name|
```

1. Надо написать запрос на выборку всех категорий нижнего уровня, у которых нет подкатегорий.
2. Надо написать запрос на выборку всех категорий, которые имеют не более 5 подкатегорий.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM category WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT parent_id FROM category);
SELECT parent_id FROM category GROUP BY parent_id HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5;
```

Второй запрос дан при условии, что "имеют не более 5 подкатегорий" относится только к непосредственным подкатегориям.

Answer (score 0):

Данное решение (по первому вопросу) тоже допустимо. Выигрыш в производительности зависит от количества записей и индексов разумеется.

```
select *
from category c1
left join category c2 on c1.id = c2.parent_id
where c2.id is null
```